# Parsing JSON Responses Of Unknown Format For Single Value

Tags: c++, json, qt, parsing

I am creating a stock screener that sources data from  ultiple apis. I would like to parse api responses from various apis for a single value.

I am using stock data apis that return JSON in different nested formats. Since the format of the JSON can be different, e.g. root could be an object or an array.. I am having trouble understanding how to go about this. I have successfully parsed JSON responses when the format is known. I am using qt, with no 3rd party libs, which seems to require that you parse these responses explcitly as I have done previously. How do I create a generic JSON parser that? Is this even possible?

Example: For this JSON response.. I would like to parse for "value"

```
{
  "historical_data": [
    {
      "date": "2019-06-28",
      "value": 197.92
    }
  ],
  "security": {
    "id": "sec_agjrgj",
    "company_id": "com_NX6GzO",
    "stock_exchange_id": "sxg_ozMr9y",
    "name": "Apple Inc",
    "code": "EQS",
    "currency": "USD",
    "ticker": "AAPL",
    "composite_ticker": "AAPL:US",
    "figi": "BBG000B9Y5X2",
    "composite_figi": "BBG000B9XRY4",
    "share_class_figi": "BBG001S5N8V8"
  },
  "next_page": null
}
```

I also want to parse this JSON repsone for "value"

```
{
  "date": "2019-06-28",
  "value": 197.92
}
```

I am trying to not write a parser function for each api I use. I would like to be able to find if the JSON has a "value" and if so.. return its value.

Comment: What about recursively walking through the JSON three, searching for elements with "value" key?

Comment: That’s essentially what I had in mind. I’m not 100% sure what that looks like though.

Comment: What if `"security"` object also have "value" value?

Comment: Good question. Assuming this would never happen, how would one go about this parsing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for this. For example, using the [jsoncons](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons/blob/master/doc/ref/jsonpath/jsonpath.md) implementation of JsonPath, you can write

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <jsoncons/json.hpp>
#include <jsoncons_ext/jsonpath/json_query.hpp>

using namespace jsoncons;

int main()
{
    std::string data = /* your JSON response */;

    json root = json::parse(data);
    // json_query returns an array of items that match the JsonPath expression
    json result = jsonpath::json_query(root, "$..value");
    for (const auto& item : result.array_range())
    {
        std::cout << item << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
197.92
```